# How to build a dropdown menu with data generated from xml file

Tags: jquery, xml, menu, drop-down-menu

Is their any good article to build a dropdown menu ,with data being obtained from xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use something like the [Xmenu](http://www.the-di-lab.com/?p=87) jQuery plugin.